# Python: get all content of specific XML tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have parsed a XML file and need to get all content from all `<name>` tags.

So far I've come up with this:

```
xml_tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('person')[0].toxml()
xml_data = xml_tag.replace('<name>','').replace('</name>','')
```

This however only gets the first tag. How do I create a list of all the name tags content in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually I use lxml for these things but looking at your code, this or somethin similar should work.

```
xml_tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('person')[0]
xml_data = [elem.nodeValue for elem in dom.getElementsByTagName('name')]
```

Comment: It seems, this creates a list of "None" values.

Comment: elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue fixed it. Thanks!